# How to show data based on month

Tags: react-native

I have a response as below

```json
{
  "Id": 1444,
  "data":
  [
    {
       "Date": "24 may 2021",
       "type":{
         "Id": 5578,
         "Name": "type1"
       }
    },
    {
       "Date": "25 may 2022",
       "type":{
         "Id": 5556,
         "Name": "type9"
       }
    },
   {
       "Date": "24 may 2021",
       "type":{
         "Id": 6667
         "Name": "type5"
       }
   },
   {
      "Date": "28 Feb 2021"
       "type":{
         "Id": 788
         "Name": "type7"
       }
    },
  ]
}
```

Now I have to do group by on month for eg. which ever data belongs to Feb months is show together and which where data belongs to march month is shown together, please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: FYI I attempted to format your JSON response, but... it's not valid JSON (missing quotes, for example). As for grouping: Please edit to show your code and your specific problem. As written, this is a general requirement, followed by a request for the Community to solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Because your JSON isnt a valid object I decided to just randomly create dates with this:

```js
 const months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
  ];
  const getRandom = (min = 0, max = 1) => {
    let range = max - min;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * range + min);
  };
  const randomDates = (num) => {
    let emptyArray = Array(num).fill(null);
    return emptyArray.map((nil) => {
      const monthIndex = getRandom(0, months.length);
      return {
        day: getRandom(1, 28),
        year: getRandom(2015, 2022),
        month: months[monthIndex],
      };
    });
  };
  const dates = randomDates(10);
  const initialValue = {};
  //give initialValue keys of month that are arrays
  months.forEach((month) =>{
    initialValue[month] = []
    });
  console.log(initialValue);
  const splitDates = dates.reduce((prevVal, currentVal) => {
    let month = currentVal.month;
    prevVal[month].push(currentVal);
    return prevVal
  }, initialValue);
  console.log(splitDates);
```

Comment: To fit your actual use case you would have to parse the month from each item in `response.data` but I'll leave that to you